# how to find the latest version information from curl output

Tags: unix

I have below outcome from curl and I want latest version `3.15.11.170827.alpha-25` from below list

```
<a href="3.15.1.alpha-20/">3.15.1.alpha-20/</a>          04-Jul-2020 17:33    -
<a href="3.15.10.170764.alpha-24/">3.15.10.170764.alpha-24/</a>  04-Aug-2020 08:47    -
<a href="3.15.11.170827.alpha-25/">3.15.11.170827.alpha-25/</a>  04-Aug-2020 09:50    -
<a href="3.15.2.155956.alpha-21/">3.15.2.155956.alpha-21/</a>   04-Jul-2020 17:52    -
<a href="3.15.3.155957.alpha-0/">3.15.3.155957.alpha-0/</a>    04-Jul-2020 18:00    -
<a href="3.15.4.155958.alpha-22/">3.15.4.155958.alpha-22/</a>   04-Jul-2020 18:06    -
<a href="3.15.5.155959.alpha-23/">3.15.5.155959.alpha-23/</a>   04-Jul-2020 18:11    -
<a href="3.15.6.157518.alpha-0/">3.15.6.157518.alpha-0/</a>    08-Jul-2020 11:24    -
<a href="3.15.8.157838.alpha-1/">3.15.8.157838.alpha-1/</a>    08-Jul-2020 15:39    -
<a href="3.15.9.158265.alpha-2/">3.15.9.158265.alpha-2/</a>    09-Jul-2020 10:41    -
```

I tried below option `grep -oP '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.alpha-+[0-9]*' | sort`  but it's not working. It shows wrong version. How can I sort based on date or any other way? i.e. it should always shows `3.15.11.170827.alpha-25`

Answer (score 0):

If you have gnu sort with `-V`, you can do:

```
cut -d'"' -f2 input | sort -rV | sed  1q
```

If you do not, you can try:

```
sort -t. -k1,1rn -k2,2rn -k3,3rn -k4,4rn
```

(retaining the pre-filter which was just remove for clarity).  Not all of your versions have a numeric 4th column, so maybe you want to use `-k4,4r` instead.

Comment: yes, i used the same but only for column 3 and 4. thanks.